# Laravel 5: Undefined variable return_array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to get data with ajax call, and after sending the ajax call i want to store data in array, but I'm getting this error when I open the page.

```
Undefined variable: return_array
```

My function

```
public function findUser(Request $request) {
    $findUserInput = $request->get('name');
    $user = DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', $findUserInput)
        ->first();

    $data =  DB::select("SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$user'");

    foreach ($data as $da) {
        $return_array[] = $da;
    } 

    return $return_array;      
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting `$return_array = [];` above `foreach`

Comment: define `$return_array = array();` bfore loop

Comment: you can also add `if(count($data) > 0) {foreach....}`

Comment: Oh damn, what i missed..thank you!

Comment: $data =  DB::select("SELECT * FROM users where name='$user'");
this line is wrong
you are try to use an array instead of string
the $user is ana array of user not the name
you should use $user->name

Comment: @MoawiaMeghari yes i see the mistake

Comment: @epowah the $user and $data are the same query and they return an object with user data from users table

Comment: another thing you should define the array before the foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgot to declare this variable:

```
public function findUser(Request $request) {
    $return_array = [];
```